# Keeping spaces in textarea (JavaScript variable)

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, spaces

I have a variable in JavaScript that contains the contents of an html textarea. When I print the variable all that were entered by the user are forgotten. Is there any way to find the spaces in the string so I can separate each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML collapses [adjacent whitespace](http://www-sul.stanford.edu/tools/tutorials/html2.0/whitespace.html) - so if you are displaying within HTML, that's what you are seeing.

You can replace spaces with non break spaces: `&nbsp;` - this will ensure they are displayed in HTML and not collapsed.

Another option is to place them in a [`<pre>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.3.4) element

Comment: Thanks, I have a better understanding of how HTML treats user input now but I should have been more specific about what I'm needing to do... It is important that I know where the user has entered a new line in the textarea. Is there any way of locating the spaces in the JavaScript variable?

Comment: @Alex - And what _do_ you need to do?

Answer (score 1):

here is a function , you can use for your script:

```
function nl2br (str) {
 var breakTag = ''; return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1'+ breakTag +'$2'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean all newlines? HTML ignores newlines and collapses whitespace by default. Print them inside a `<pre>` tag, or check out the CSS `white-space` property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

You can also replace newlines with `<br>` tags using:

```
while (str.indexOf("\n") > -1) str = str.replace("\n","<br>");
```

Comment: thanks, the JavaScript variable already contained the spaces, the HTML was just removing them when I was printing it.